# Android broadcast receiver not receiving intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-broadcast

I have two apps that I made, and am trying to send an intent from one to the other but the intent is never getting to the `onReceive()` however this problem is only one way. The first app can send to the second but the second cannot send back info. I am using a different intent action to send from the second to the first but otherwise they are identical. Any ideas on why this might not be working? I have tried everything I can think of and read most of the posts I could find on here and to no avail.

It's not crashing or giving me any indications as to what is happening in the logcat it's just doing nothing.

send function

```
private void sendFinishLog(String ID, String Cond)
{
    Log.d("me", "send finish log");
    Intent logIntent = new Intent();
    logIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);
    logIntent.putExtra("Cond", Cond);
    logIntent.setAction("com.me.intent.finishlog");
    Log.d("me","logIntent : " + logIntent.toString()   
        +logIntent.getExtras().toString());
    sendBroadcast(logIntent);
}
```

receive class

```
public class LogReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static ArrayList<LogDataHolder> logData = new ArrayList<LogDataHolder>();
    private boolean found;
    static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    private static String lasttime;
    private static String now = "Boot time";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context cont, Intent logIntent) 
    {
        Log.d("me","On receive");
                etc.....
    }
```

Receiving app manifest

```
<!-- for receiving logs  -->
<receiver 
    android:name = "LogReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent_filter>
        <action android:name="com.me.intent.finishlog" />
    </intent_filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: did you register the receiver?

Comment: Does it not amount to the same thing? And I want it to always be listening so I can pick it up whenever it is triggered so the manifest way is the better option for this, from what I understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

something like:

```
public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mLogReceiver,filter);
}
```

and for un-register:

```
public void onPause() {
    getActivity().unregsiterReceiver(mLogreceiver);
}
```

**edit:**
i just figured that your LogReceiver-class has no constructor neither. you will need to write one aswell:

```
private LogReceiver mLogReceiver = new LogReceiver() {
```

and after that you can use the onReceive-method like you have it already in your code.

Comment: the overriden onReceive-method has to be inside the {} of my last line.

Comment: is that valid for the constructor aswell?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it was this or a combo of all the answers but this has got it working, so thank you. Not sure why I needed this when I have done it without this before but it works and that's all that matters for now.

Comment: lol at least you learned that sometimes you just have to be persistent and keep on coding :-)

Comment: @bofredo Shouldn't your methods be calling `super.onResume()` and `super.onPause()`?

Answer (score 5):

Try it again like this. The category may need to be added

```
<receiver
    android:name = "LogReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.me.intent.finishlog" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: What does the default mean though? Does it mean a standard android one or can it be used for custom intent actions?

Comment: If you do not have to add an action, you do not need to add category .But if you add the action, I think it necessary to add a category to indicate how to use this action

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved when I removed the receiver unregister from the OnPause(). method.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the receiver in the manifest as:

```
    android:name = "LogReceiver"
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) states that name should be:

> The name of the class that implements the broadcast receiver, a
>   subclass of BroadcastReceiver. This should be a fully qualified class
>   name (such as, "com.example.project.ReportReceiver"). However, as a
>   shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for
>   example, ". ReportReceiver"), it is appended to the package name
>   specified in the  element.

In other words, it needs to include the package. Try changing the name to:

```
    android:name = ".LogReceiver"
```

or

```
    android:name = "com.me.yourpackagename.LogReceiver"
```

Comment: Post a complete project.

Comment: complete project is >50,000 lines of code so that isn't really an option

Comment: Then create a small project involving only the receiver.